# Custom theme style "glitching" android application

Tags: android, android-layout, xamarin.android

When attempting to add a splash screen to a Xamarin Android app I'm developing, I've found [this article on Xamarin guides](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/user_interface/creating_a_splash_screen/) that explains how to make a splash screen.

After adding a new style and adding it to the `Activity` - which worked wonderfully - all the fragments that I had using `GridView` or `ListView` with `ImageView` on it completely glitched out, as if the images were dragged from the top to the bottom of the screen - and also expanding the `View` height as if it was with the `layout_height` set to `match_parent`.

I have to point out that the glitch only happens if I set the `Theme` on the `Activity` to the custom theme style, like this:

```
[Activity(
    MainLauncher = true, NoHistory = true,
    ScreenOrientation = ScreenOrientation.Portrait,
    Theme = "@style/SplashTheme" )]
```

If I change the `Theme` to other theme, or remove it, the glitch does not happen ( nor the splash is shown, which I need it ).

What could possibly be the fault here?

**Resource Theme Style**

```
<style name="SplashTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/SplashScreen</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>
```

---

Some fragments **without** the theme being applied:

```
https://i.gyazo.com/ea54dc92a4b02b8acce592520434ae88.png
https://i.gyazo.com/900a729c075f510ec40886a5a3258167.png
https://i.gyazo.com/e25f069ea32fd3e5aeb8c37bba4c97a9.png
```

Some fragments **with** the theme being applied:

```
https://i.gyazo.com/0de59e7bf285e5c45ad647c9ba8393e5.png
https://i.gyazo.com/794f55bf4297322763fbc9eede9310db.png
https://i.gyazo.com/6155baf4d8d4166f3da619aa48adfd77.png
```

<sub>*I apologize the fact that I have to put the bare urls to the images instead of having them right here, for some reason SO editor is throwing an error saying that the post contains code that is not formatted when I attempt to put the images. If someone know how to put the correctly, fell free to do it.*</sub>

The image that is showing on the glitched versions is the image defined on the **SplashTheme** `background`

---

### Solution

The glitches - that were caused only on `GridView` and `ListView` - are caused due to the fact that I kept tracking of the root activity to inflate layouts and, since I was using *that* activity which had the custom style applied, the `GridView` and `ListView` when inflated would have the custom theme also applied.

The workaround I had to implement was, when setting the `Adapter` for a `ListView` or `GridView`, sending also a reference to the parent `Activity` to inflate the layouts.

Answer (score 0):

Putting it simple, the glitch was caused by using the `Activity` that had the custom theme applied to inflate other views.

---

In my project I have an `Activity` that is the ***Root*** of the application. It handles some properties about the device and some other data. Then, other `Activity`s would manage specific ***Sections*** of the application.

So, having that in mind, I had this - *which was causing the glitch*:

```
View view = convertView ??
    Root.LayoutInflater.Inflate( Resource.Layout.BrandsListViewItemTemplate, null );
```

Now, while I was using the ***Root*** to inflate the layouts of the `GridView` and `ListView`, the theme applied to the `Activity` was also being applied to the inflated `View`s.

To fix this issue I simply started using the ***Section*** instead of the ***Root***. Although it isn't that much of a difference, here's the code with the fix applied:

```
View view = convertView ??
    Section.LayoutInflater.Inflate( Resource.Layout.BrandsListViewItemTemplate, null );
```

---

Putting it in a *full view*:

**Activity** *Root*

```
[Activity(
    MainLauncher = true,
    Theme = "@style/SplashTheme" )]
public class RootActivityClass : Activity {
    protected override void OnResume() {
        StartActivity( typeof( SectionActivityClass ) );
    }
}
```

**Activity** *Section*

```
public class SectionActivityClass : Activity {
    protected override void OnCreate( Bundle savedInstancesState ) {
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = FragmentManager.BeginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.Replace( /* Resource Id */, new FragmentClass( this ) );
        fragmentTransaction.Commit();
    }
}
```

**Fragment**

```
public class FragmentClass : Fragment {
    SectionActivityClass Root;

    protected override void OnCreate( Bundle savedInstancesState ) {
        base.OnCreateView( inflater, container, savedInstanceState );

        View currentView = inflater.Inflate( /* Resource Layout */, null );

        GridView gridView = currentView.FindViewById<GridView>( /* GridView Id */ );
        gridView.Adapter = new GridViewAdapterClass( Root );

        return currentView;
    }

    public FragmentClass( SectionActivityClass root ) {
        Root = root;
    }
}
```

**Adapter**

```
public class GridViewAdapterClass : BaseAdapter<Object> {
    SectionActivityClass Root;

    public override View GetView( Int32 position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent ) {
// Now, since I'm passing a reference to the 'SectionActivityClass' nothing bad happens,
//      but if I was passing a reference to the 'RootActivityClass'
//      the theme would be applied to the view and would "glitch" the view

        View view = convertView ?? Root.LayoutInflater.Inflate( /* Resource Layout */, null );

        /* . . . */

        return view;
    }

    public BrandsListViewAdapter( SectionActivityClass root ) : base() {
        Root = root;
    }
}
```